# how add more details to to paypal buy button

Tags: html, paypal

I use this sample code for paypal buy button:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="b@emeil.ir">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="beach ball">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="15">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="towel">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="20">

<input type="submit" value="buy">
</form>
```

now I want add more details about items such as quantity and size to be shown in **Your order summary** in paypal window.

how can I add this details to code?

**update:** I founded this way to add quantity for every item:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="b@emeil.ir">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="beach ball">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="15">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="3">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="towel">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="20">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="2">

<input type="submit" value="buy">
</form>
```

but now how to add custom details such as size and etc... ?

Answer (score 0):

For multiple item purchases, you can use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1">
```

This will prompt the user to input the quantity in the next page.